# React Query String showing 404 when provided with query parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new to React and trying to render a page based on the name query like 
http://localhost:3000/show?name=james

So I initially added the Route as :

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Switch>    
<Route path='*' component={ErrorComponent} />} />
<Route path="show(/:name)" name="name" component={Show}></Route>
</Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And then I tried to render the component Show like below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import queryString from 'query-string';
class Show extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props.location.search);
    const values = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    console.log(values.name);
  }


  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.match;
    return <div>
      <h4>About</h4>
      <p>This is About page.</p>
      {params.id ? <b>ID: {params.id}</b> : <i>ID is optional.</i>}
    </div>
  }
}

export default Show;
```

then when I try to show the page

http://localhost:3000/show?name=james

It always show 404. Not sure which part I am doing it wrong. Any help is appreciated. 
Also I am using react-router-dom 5.1.2 .
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Can't believe I didn't notice this originally...

You need to put your `path="*"` route at the bottom of the `Switch` otherwise it'll match everything and anything below it won't even have a chance to match since `Switch`es match only a single route. The description of making sure you have your route path set up correctly (below) is applicable as well, of course.

```
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/show/:name?" component={ShowRouteParam} />
        <Route path="*">ERROR 404</Route>
      </Switch>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-browser-d0sew?file=/src/App.js

---

The routes don't match query parameters.

> "Please note: The RegExp returned by path-to-regexp is intended for
> use with pathnames or hostnames. It can not handle the query strings
> or fragments of a URL."

Depending on how you want to do it, you can either make the id an optional part of the route, or let it be a normal query parameters

Option 1:

```
<Route path="/show/:name?" component={Show}></Route>
```

component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import queryString from 'query-string';
class Show extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props.location.search);
    const values = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    console.log(values.name);
  }


  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.match;
    return <div>
      <h4>About</h4>
      <p>This is About page.</p>
      {params.name ? <b>ID: {params.name}</b> : <i>Name is optional.</i>}
    </div>
  }
}

export default Show;
```

Option 2:

```
<Route path="/show" component={Show}></Route>
```

component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import queryString from 'query-string';
class Show extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props.location.search);
    const values = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    console.log(values.name);
  }


  render() {
    const values = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    return <div>
      <h4>About</h4>
      <p>This is About page.</p>
      {values.name ? <b>ID: {values.name}</b> : <i>Name is optional.</i>}
    </div>
  }
}

export default Show;
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-rain-n61zs

Comment: Hi Zachary thanks for your explanation but still after trying your 2 solutions it complains for a 404. Is it anything to do with route?

Comment: Okay, I fixed the error in this. We were missing the initial route / in the route path. I also included a working example on codesandbox. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I can understand the logic but when I try this in my App and call the browser with http://localhost:3000/show?name=james it should render the page right .but it is still 404 .And I am also using Browser router is that the case

Comment: Can you add what you've changed your code to underneath the prompt?
Or set up a codesandbox with it so it's easier to debug?

Comment: @ZacharyHaber I am coming across the same issue as Ricky. I have pretty much the same setup as your codesandbox example but for some reason when I click the link whilst on the same page, it goes to the 404 page. But if I enter the url manually, the link works. I have this at the bottom of my Router routes and it seems to be redirecting to this rather the new url with updated query params:   <Route component={Error} />

Comment: @UsmanJ, I updated my answer as I realized I goofed a bit. If the update doesn't fix your issue, I'd really need to see a reproducible example to be able to assist.

Comment: @ZacharyHaber I gave that a go but still no luck. Here is an example of what my code looks like: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-shamir-nt25m Thanks for your help.

Comment: @UsmanJ You need to have your query string separated into the search property of the `to` parameter: `<Link to={pathname:'/a',search:'q=hi'} />`. It seems that react router tries to assume that the pathname is in fact a path even if there are query params included in it.
https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-platform-q6ry7

Comment: @ZacharyHaber Thank you very much. That solved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

> `path="show(/:name)"`

This isn't a valid URL path to match on.

Redefine the path to `["/show/:id", "/show"]`

```
<Route path={["/show/:id", "/show"]} name="name" component={Show} />
```

And since the `Route` is directly rendering the component, it can pull the query parameters and match parameters straight from props (`this.props.match.params` & `this.props.location.search`). Specifying two matching paths is equivalent to defining two separate `Route`s that render the same component. The same rules apply to path specificity, so define more complex matches first within the array.

```
class Show extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props.location.search);
    const values = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    console.log(values.name);
  }

  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.match;
    return <div>
      <h4>About</h4>
      <p>This is About page.</p>
      {params.id ? <b>ID: {params.id}</b> : <i>ID is optional.</i>}
    </div>
  }
}
```

[image: Edit frosty-banach-9ou2q]